# How to delete data in magento 2 custom table?

Tags: magento2, php, magento-community

I want to delete id 5 data from my table.
I used some code but show:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Sparsh\CRUD\Controller\Index\Delete\Interceptor
```

My controller:

```
<?php
namespace Sparsh\CRUD\Controller\Index;
use Sparsh\CRUD\Model\postFactory;
class Delete extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $_pageFactory;
     protected $_postFactory;
 
     public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
          \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
          \Sparsh\CRUD\Model\PageFactory $postFactory
          )
     {
          $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
          $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
          return parent::__construct($context);
     }
 
     public function execute()
     {
        //   echo "Delete controller";
        //   exit;
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam(5);
        try {
            $model = $this->_postFactory->create();
            $model->load($id);
            $model->delete();
            echo "Success";

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            echo "Error";
        }
        // var_dump($id->getData());
        // exit;


     }
}
```

My model:

```
<?php
namespace Sparsh\CRUD\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

 

class Post extends AbstractModel
{
        protected function _construct()
        {
                $this->_init('Sparsh\CRUD\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
        }
 
       
 
}
```

My Recourse Model:

```
<?php

namespace Sparsh\CRUD\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Post extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('post', 'post_id'); //hello is table of module
    }
}
```

My collection:

```
<?php
namespace Sparsh\CRUD\Model\ResourceModel\Post;
 
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
        /**
         * Define resource model
         *
         * @return void
         */

        protected function _construct()
        {
                $this->_init('Sparsh\CRUD\Model\Post', 'Sparsh\CRUD\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
           
        }
  
}
```

What is the problem ?
I am new in Magento.
IS there any solution?

Comment: Seems like the answer is somewhere below - but just to point out you should ideally use your resource model to `load()` and `delete()` entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Error is in your controller where you add this use **Sparsh\CRUD\Model\postFactory;**. Use Capital P write like this **Sparsh\CRUD\Model\PostFactory;** clear your cache and re-run.

Comment: its not work .I use your  instruction but same.

Comment: In your public function __construct() replace third dependency(\Sparsh\CRUD\Model\PageFactory $postFactory) with this(PostFactory $postFactory) .